# Syncing vast amount of test data to iOS device

Tags: ios, testing, data-synchronization

In an automated test environment, I have to use 7.5GB of test data, that consists of 170k+ files. Simply copying it with the bundle is too slow (40+ minutes), thus I would like to incrementally sync the contents of the test data folder between the iOS device and the mac. Eg. using the iOS device as a USB drive, and use rsync to sync the contents, but any ideas are welcome. No, I can't jailbreak the device. Basically I want to keep two folders synchronized between an iOS test suite and a mac. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe try to mount a ftp server on the mac and rsync from the app using librsync ?

Comment: Unfortunately we can't use LGPL :( Now I am trying to launch a webdav server on iOS, and mount it on the mac, then use rsync on the mac to sync the folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to do that using USB without jailbreaking your iOS device. The whole setup works via a UNIX socket called `usbmuxd` that Apple uses to communicate between a USB iOS device and e.g. Xcode or iTunes on a Mac. The iOS device basically opens a TCP server and the OSX app connects to the UNIX socket from which it can obtain a TCP connection to server on the iOS device. After that you can just write and read data over USB using streams at 480MBits.

There are some frameworks under MIT license with example apps for OSX and iOS that allow you to use this mechanism in your own apps:

https://github.com/jensmeder/DarkLightning
https://github.com/rsms/peertalk

This mechanism is App Store compliant in case u need to publish your app later. One popular example is an app called [Duet Display](https://www.duetdisplay.com) that allows you to use your iPad as a second screen via USB.

Hope that helps.